# Error in accessing our office VPN at other location

Tags: vpn

Below explained is the network setup we have in our 3 offices at locations say B,D,T.

At each location we have some Security router to enable VPN at each office site.
We have explicity asked our ISPs to get static IP addresses for these security routers(for each of the VPN). And then the internal network computers, devices have private IP addresses. Now location D and T are working fine, as in any computer inside the network just powers up and can see the computers/intranet sites in each others sites. It was working fine even in the B location, wherein we could access computers/intranet sites from D and T locations.

Recently we moved to another office at B location. The ISP gave us a static IP address to us but inspite of configuring those details(IP Address, Subway mask, Gateway, DNS given by ISP) in our router Wan settings (Our router is Draytek Vigor 2910 model), then after reboot of router and switch(a netgear) the computers cannot access the Internet itself, leave alone accessing our other office sites.

**Question 1:** What could be wrong here? Anything that we are missing? I can provide mroe details if needed?

**Question 2:** So then if we change our Draytek router Wan settings to "OBtain IP address automatically/Dynamic IP address", we can access outside world internet atleast, but not our office VPNs at location D and T. To do that we have to explicitly create a VPN connection on our individual computers and connect to the VPN using exisitng network.

Why do you think we need Static IP address for our Security router(Draytek box) for getting this VPN setup working(Which is not working anyway)? Why Dynamic IP addresses doesn't work? Any reason?

We are exasperated in getting this to sort out. Any pointers useful.

Comment: This might be better suited in serverfault?

Comment: @jmreicha - SU also has many VPN questions.

Comment: Since you can use the dynamic IP you got from DHCP, I suspect your ISP gave you the wrong information or put your link on the wrong network/vlan. You should check if the static address you get from them and the dynamic address are in the same subnet. If they're drastically different, you should definitely contact your ISP and see what's wrong.